# How to redirect in HTML?

Tags: html

I was wondering how I could redirect to another page using HTML only. Could any body help??? Sorry but I am  to programing :) I have done some research in books but that did;t help:(:(:(. The links I want are from index.php to facebook.com/help. I have tried the code bellow but it didn;t work

> Goto="facebook.com/help"

I really appreciate your help and will credit you in my site. I have also tried

```
Navigate="facebook.com/help"
```

Regards,

The Dev Web Team

Comment: "The Dev Web Team" You mean a whole team of you don't know how to use Google?

Comment: i normally build my websites using `build="thisWebsite.psDoItGood"` and everything works pretty good.

Comment: First ask this to Google

Comment: I think you're confused about what HTML is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ever heard of Google before?????

This is the code that goes in the head:

> `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://facebook.com/help/" />`

Comment: @user3572995: How did you get here? That's google ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just a plain anchor in html:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">click here</a>
```